# Pi 3 not able to read the SD card, the green LED is blinking

Tags: pi-3, sd-card

I found that there may be a problem with pins of the SD card reader but I can't find anything wrong.

The pins on the right touch when the SD card is inserted but not with one on the extreme right. Is this a problem?

Comment: The pins *aren't touching*, like at all? Of course this is a problem, how else would they function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think the SD card slot is damaged, then you can attempt a repair (not recommended), or return the Pi to the seller for a new one.

The number of times the LED blinks is indicative as to what the problem could be:

- 3 flashes: start.elf not found
- 4 flashes: start.elf not launched
- 7 flashes: kernel.img not found
- 8 flashes: SDRAM not recognised. You need newer bootcode.bin/start.elf firmware

I recommend trying a new SD card just to be certain its not the SD card slot.

Comment: It was non returnable item and tried a repair.So, found out that pins that touch when card is inserted ,overlapped otinstead of touching each other. Luckily I was able to fix that . Thanks for your suggestion !